# xslt, how to 'flatten' the tag structure for unknown number of child tags

Tags: xslt, flatten

My source file looks like this:

```
<x>
<names>
         <name>name1</name>
         <name>name2</name>
</names>
<codes>
         <code>code1</code>
         <code>code2</code>
</codes>
<stuff> stuff </stuff>
</x>
```

And I'd like to transform it to get this output:

```
<out>
<y>
    <name>name1</name>
    <code>code1</code>
    <stuff> stuff </stuff>
</y>
<y>
    <name>name2</name>
    <code>code2</code>
    <stuff> stuff </stuff>
</y>
</out>
```

I don't know the number of name and code tags in source file, but I do know the numer of names equals number of codes.

Please share some tips, how to do it.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <out>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="names/name"/>
  </out>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="name">
  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
  <y>
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   <xsl:copy-of select=
     "../../codes/code[position()=$vPos]"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="/*/stuff"/>
  </y>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<x>
    <names>
        <name>name1</name>
        <name>name2</name>
    </names>
    <codes>
        <code>code1</code>
        <code>code2</code>
    </codes>
    <stuff> stuff </stuff>
</x>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<out>
   <y>
      <name>name1</name>
      <code>code1</code>
      <stuff> stuff </stuff>
   </y>
   <y>
      <name>name2</name>
      <code>code2</code>
      <stuff> stuff </stuff>
   </y>
</out>
```

Comment: works perfectly, thanks. I understood how to do simmilar transformations in the future.